# How can I import a model from a Source Engine game into Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-4, 3d-modeling, source-engine

I am currently developing a game in Unreal Engine 4. This project is for personal use, and will not be exhibited or sold.

Because I have no talent, I need to snatch some models from some Source Engine games.

Does anyone happen to know how I would port these models into UE4?

I have Blender and Crowbar already installed.

Comment: Do you have access to the project files of the Source Engine game you want to borrow the models from or do you only have the compiled games?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself but quick google resulted in promising find: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQPxEy66DC0 its for CS:GO, but cs:go is made on source engine so it shouldn't be different from other source engine games.